# identifying columns with similar endings to perform mathematical functions

Tags: r, function

I have a `data.frame` with multiple columns with similar names for different types of exercise, recording the weight used, number of repititions and number of sets. In my MWE it is bicep curls and lateral raises. All the different exercises have similar ending column names: `Wt` `Sets` `Reps`

Is there a way to calculated `Wt * Reps * Sets` for each exercise, save the result as a new column ending `Load`, and then add all columns ending `Load` for `Total_load`?

MWE:

```
exercise =  data.frame(BicWt= c( 3,3,4),
                       BicSets = c(2,2,2),
                       BicReps = c(10,12,12),
                       LatWt = c(4,4,4),
                       LatSets = c( 2,2,2),
                       LatReps = c(6,8,10))

 BicWt BicSets BicReps LatWt LatSets LatReps
1     3       2      10     4       2       6
2     3       2      12     4       2       8
3     4       2      12     4       2      10
```

Desired output is:

```
BicWt BicSets BicReps BicLoad LatWt LatSets LatReps LatLoad Total_Load
1     3       2      10      60     4       2       6      48        108
2     3       2      12      72     4       2       8      64        136
3     4       2      12      96     4       2      10      80        176
```

where `BicLoad` = `BicWt` * `BicSets` * `BicReps` etc.

**EDIT**

Some of the exercise columns have CAPITAL letters before Wt,Reps and Sets.

```
exercise =  data.frame(BicWt= c( 3,3,4),
                       BicSets = c(2,2,2),
                       BicReps = c(10,12,12),
                       LatWt = c(4,4,4),
                       LatSets = c( 2,2,2),
                       LatReps = c(6,8,10),
                       PullUpWt = c(5,5,5),
                       PullUpSets = c(2,2,2),
                       PullUpReps = c(6,8,10))
```

```
BicWt BicSets BicReps BicLoad LatWt LatSets LatReps LatLoad PullUpWt PullUpSets PullUpReps PullUpLoad Total_Load
1     3       2      10      60     4       2       6      48        5          2          6         60        168
2     3       2      12      72     4       2       8      64        5          2          8         80        216
3     4       2      12      96     4       2      10      80        5          2         10        100        276
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could remove the suffix part of the column names and split into a `list` of data.frames, then do elementwise multiply with `Reduce` on those datasets.  Create the total by doing elementwise sum across the `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(split.default(exercise, 
     sub("[A-Z][a-z]+$", "", names(exercise))), \(x) Reduce(`*`, x))
exercise[paste0(names(lst1), "Load")] <- lst1
exercise$Total_Load <- Reduce(`+`, lst1)
```

-output

```
> exercise
  BicWt BicSets BicReps LatWt LatSets LatReps BicLoad LatLoad Total_Load
1     3       2      10     4       2       6      60      48        108
2     3       2      12     4       2       8      72      64        136
3     4       2      12     4       2      10      96      80        176
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`, create the 'BicLoad', 'LatLoad' columns individually by looping `across` the 'Bic', 'Lat' columns, do the elementwise multiplication with `reduce` and create the 'Total_load' by adding the BicLoad and LatLoad

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
exercise %>%
   mutate(BicLoad = across(starts_with('Bic')) %>%
      reduce(`*`), .after = BicReps) %>% 
   mutate(LatLoad = across(starts_with('Lat')) %>% 
    reduce(`*`), .after = LatReps) %>%
   mutate(Total_Load = BicLoad + LatLoad)
```

-output

```
BicWt BicSets BicReps BicLoad LatWt LatSets LatReps LatLoad Total_Load
1     3       2      10      60     4       2       6      48        108
2     3       2      12      72     4       2       8      64        136
3     4       2      12      96     4       2      10      80        176
```

Comment: That's really helpful. I usually prefer `tidyverse` solutions because of their easier intelligibility. In this case, the `base` `R` solution is quicker because of the many columns in real dataset. I was going to as how it works for column names with multiple capital letters, but "[A-Z][a-z]+$" seems to work with all the relevant patterns.